# How to use iPhone to send Bluetooth to a speaker playing the music from my PC HDD?

Tags: bluetooth, pc

I have a PC which has no bluetooth and want to play music this PC to a bluetooth speaker using my iPhone as the bluetooth sender.  PC and iphone could be connected via usb cable or wifi that is not a problem.

Comment: Are you trying to send music from PC -> iPhone -> Bluetooth -> Speaker?  It's a bit difficult to tell from your question.

Comment: Yes excuse my english PC-> iPhone-> speaker The idea is use the iphone as a bluetooth send from PC to speaker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use your iPhone as a receiver of music (either from wifi or cable) from your PC in the manner you appear to indicate.

However, if you have iTunes installed on the PC, you can use iTunes to access your music first.  Then, use the iPhone to access the music through iTunes.  Once you've got the music playing, you can output it to your BT speaker.  It's actually much simpler than it looks in print!

You would need to setup your devices to use **Home Sharing**.  Start by following the guide in [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202190) on Home Sharing.  All devices must be on the same network for this to work.

[Here's another walk-through](https://www.howtogeek.com/209429/how-to-share-your-itunes-library-with-your-iphone-or-ipad/) on how to set this up and it might be a little easier to follow.

The benefit of this setup is when you add more devices, like Apple TV or an iPad, they can also access this same music using Home Sharing.

Comment: You are the master. I'm listening Bad (the MJ album really good) in loudspeakers right now. Thank you so much, this was really easy even for a tech-neanderthal like me

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help!

Answer (score -2):

Spotify also has this option. ;)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions